# Best way to search for a string in a column in Spark DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using Apache Spark 2.2 with Scala 2.11.

I have a string, from which I create 1-gram, 2-gram and 3-gram. After that I try to  search those values in a dataframe. Now this process happens many times due to which the whole Spark job is taking a lot of time. How should I think any differently?

Following is the code snippet:

```
// creating the n-grams
val vNGrams = for (i <- 1 to 3) yield sampleString.trim.split(" ").sliding(i).map(p => p.mkString(" "))  

// converting them to a single array as above code generates three different iterators for different ngrams
val z = vNGrams.map(itr => itr.toArray).flatten.toArray

for (i <- 0 to z.length-1) {
  val df = vSomeTable.select("COUNTRY_CODE").where(upper(col("ZIPCODE")) === z(i).toUpperCase)
  if(df.count.toInt > 0) {
    countryCode = df.take(1)(0)(0).toString
    return countryCode
  }
}
```

In Spark UI, I can see that these `count` and `take` jobs are taking time. This code snippet runs at least 20k times, also the `vSomeTable` is a dataframe having 41k rows.

Let me know if you need more information or I can do the same thing differently with less time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of multiple Spark jobs, eliminate the for-loop and use a single job instead. Also avoid using both `df.count` and `df.take` and use `limit 1` for a possibility of an early exit.

```
val z = vNGrams.flatten.map(_.toUpperCase).toArray

val rows = vSomeTable
  .select("COUNTRY_CODE")
  .where(upper(col("ZIPCODE")).isInCollection(z))
  .limit(1)
  .collect()
if (!rows.isEmpty) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: `isInCollection` came in spark 2.4 and I am using 2.2. What function should I use instead of that?

Comment: @GadaaDhaariGeek `isInCollection` is a mere convenience wrapper for `isin(z:_*)` which is available since 1.5.0

Comment: Yeah I figured that out from net only. Thanks anyway.

Comment: But the problem remains the same. Now the `collect()` is there which is taking time. What I do after getting the row is that I take the COUNTRY_CODE as a string and return it. Any help on that?

Comment: That sounds correct, `collect` is where the time should be spent, it is just arguably faster than the original version. As there is `limit 1`, it is probably easiest to collect the country code to a `Option[String]` so `...limit(1).select($"COUNTRY_CODE").collect().collectFirst { case Row(cc: String) => cc }`

Answer (score 0):

For NGram search, you can give a try to [Spark Search](https://github.com/phymbert/spark-search) - it brings [Apache Lucene](https://lucene.apache.org/) support to [spark](https://spark.apache.org/).

```scala
class MyAnalyzer extends Analyzer {
  override def createComponents(fieldName: String): TokenStreamComponents = {
    new TokenStreamComponents(new NGramTokenizer(1, 3))
  }
}
val inputRDD: RDD[Row] = ???
val otherRDD: RDD[Row] = ???
val searchRDD: SearchRDD[Row] = inputRDD.searchRDD(
  SearchOptions.builder[Row]().analyzer(classOf[MyAnalyzer]).build())
inputRDD.searchJoin(otherRDD, (r: Row) => s"ZIPCODE:${r.getString(1)}")
  .collect()
  .foreach(println)
```